# hat matching problem (Ross, p.41)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I'm studying Ross's probability book, and kind of got stuck on the matching problem.

**Suppose that each of $N$ men at a party throws his hat into the center of the room. The hats are first mixed up, and then each man randomly selects a hat. What is the probability that none of the men select their own hat?**

Solution(partial):

$P(\text{none of the men select their own hat})= 1- P( \text{at least one of the men select their own hat})$

Let: $E_i =$ the event that the ith man selects his own hat, $i=1, 2, \ldots, N$

$ E_{i_1}E_{i_2}\dots E_{i_n}$ = the event that each of the $n$ men, $i_1,i_2,\ldots, i_n$, selects his own hat

the remaining $N-n$ men: the first can select any of $N-n$ hats, the second can then select any of $N-n-1$, and so on.

Therefore, there are $(N-n)!$ combinations of the event $ E_{i_1}E_{i_2}\dots E_{i_n}$

My question is:
It looks like the solution doesn't care whether there's a match among the remaining $N-n$ men.
**but, shouldn't we care?** if there's one matched among the remaining $N-n$ men, it would be no longer be the event $ E_{i_1}E_{i_2}\dots E_{i_n}$ ?

Any hint would be very appreciate, thank you!

Comment: Please see Wikipedia, [Derangements.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) Has also come up on MSE repeatedly.

Comment: wow~ thanks! I'm now looking at it! :)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: As to your question, I hope the article, and/or MSE material, will make the Inclusion/Exclusion part of the argument clear.

Comment: just wanna make sure.... so first we ignore the chances that the event $E_{i_{1}}E_{i_{2}}...E_{i_{n}}$ may have more than ${i_{n}}$ matches, and later on, the inclusive-exclusive rule will modified the previous overestimate/underestimate ? thanks a lot!

Comment: For each sum of terms, one ignores the multiple counting. Of course, the details have  to be done right. Going through a concrete case, say $n=5$, makes the logic clear.

Comment: Recall the simplest cast: $|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$. When computing $|A|$, you don't even have $B$ in mind. Similarly, $|B|$ has nothing to do with $A$. (Indeed, it if were easy to compute $|A \setminus B|$ and $|B \setminus A|$, then you wouldn't even need inclusion-exclusion.)

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the solution focuses only on matches for a particular subset of the hats. This is a general feature of the inclusion-exclusion method: The probability that all conditions in some set $S$ hold is calculated from the probabilities for each subset $S'$ of all conditions in $S'$ holding, and in calculating that probability for $S'$ the conditions not contained in $S'$ are irrelevant.